# Sufficient way in Spark to predict number of records in given hdfs dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, count, hdfs

I have big dataset to be loaded.
I want to precompute number of partitions based on number of records.
If there are sufficient way to do this? 
Is that idea bad at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either

- run a `df.count`, which may be quite expensive
- use `df.inputFiles` and then use Hadoop Filesystem API to calculate file size (see e.g. [get size of parquet file in HDFS for repartition with Spark in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33988786/))
- or (my recommended solution) : set `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` to control how many bytes will be packed into 1 partition